# Get JQPlot element out of JQuery element

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am struggling with JQuery and JQPlot. Because my div which will hold the plot doesn't have an id I call the JQPlot function by using a JQuery element:

```
plot = jqelement.jqplot([s1, s2], { ... });
```

This doesn't return a JQPlot element though. I need a JQPlot element to be able to call the replot function and to change some parameters of the plot.

Can anybody help me getting the JQPlot element when calling the JQPlot function with a JQuery element?

Comment: Can you set an id to your jQuery element, and then retrieve it using $(el).attr('id'), to pass it to the jqplot constructor ?

Comment: +1 That would be a workaround. Thank you very much.
It still would be nice to know if my question is directly solvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the manual:-

http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/selectorSyntax.html

So in your example you can do:-

jqelement.data("jqplot").replot(); //-- access methods and options

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
var plot = $.jqplot(elem.attr('id'), data, opts);
```

I tried this to replot my chart inside hidden tabs. I modified the ui-chart angular directive (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-chart).

```
$(elem).closest('.tabpanel').bind('tabsactivate',
    function(event, ui) {
    if (plot._drawCount === 0) {
        plot.replot();
        }
});
```